# How to iterate through specific indexes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through only a specific part of a list in javascript.

In Python i've done like this:

```
board = range(101)
answer = 92
match = []
low = answer - 2
high = answer + 2

for i in board[low:high + 1]:
    match.append(i)
```

My question is how do I write a similar for loop in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over needed [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of the list

```
const board = new Array(101).fill().map((_, i) => i) //this way you can create range of [0..101]
...
board.slice(low, high+1).forEach(i=>{
  match.append(i)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that your goal is archiving the `match` result of:

```
for i in board[low:high + 1]:
   match.append(i)
```

Just use [array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
match = board.slice(low, high + 1);
```

But if your goal is to produce the **same effort** (making a loop) you could do any of this techniques:

You can do a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code) like this:

```
for (let index = low; index < (high + 1); index++) {
  match.push(board[index])
}
```

Another way could be slicing the array: ([array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

```
board = board.slice(low, high +1)
for (let index = 0; index < board.length; index++) {
  match.push(board[index])
}
```

And maybe using the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (let item in board.slice(low, high + 1)) {
  match.push(item)
}
```

Or even using slice and a forEach: [array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
board.slice(low, high + 1).forEach(function(item){
  match.push(item)
});
```

And maybe also using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
board.slice(low, high +1).forEach((i) = {
  match.push(i)
});
```

Comment: `for...in` is wrong. Did you mean [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. These different ways to do it is very helpful